# How to extract the text part only from an image using opencv and python?

Tags: python, opencv, roi, text-segmentation

Here is the image after the Pre Processed of a water meter reading...
[image]

But whenever I am using tesseract to recognize the digits its not giving an appropriate output.

So, I want to extract/segment out the digits part only as an region of Interest and to save it in a new image file, such that the tesseract can recognize it properly...

I am able to remove those extra noises in an image, that's why I am using this option.

Is there any way to do that ?

[The Unprocessed Image is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO5Jp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Before you try extracting your digits from this image, try to reduce your image size so that your digit size would be about 16 pixels height. Secondly, reduce your tesseract scanned characters whitelist to "0123456789", to avoid other characters like ",.;'/" and so on being scanned (that is quite common on this type of pictures). Lowering your image size should help tesseract to dump this noise and not scan in or mix it with digits. This method should not work by 100% on this kind of image for sure, but to clear this kind of noise would be a challenge withoud a doubt by other ways. Maybe you could try to provide us with unprocessed image if you have one, lets see what is possible then.

Comment: ThankYou @dainius
I will try out with the methods you told and I have shared the unprocessed image as you wanted to have a look at it...